# selenium can not Submit an answer in zhihu.com

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, selenium

url:https://www.zhihu.com/question/305744720/answer/557418746

use selenium can not reply answer,only human

```
options.add_experimental_option("debuggerAddress", "127.0.0.1:9222")
browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='.\chromedriver.exe',chrome_options=options)

button_li = self.browser.find_elements_by_class_name('Button--blue')
if len(button_li) > 2:
    print(len(button_li))
    button_ele = button_li[4]
    button_ele.click()
time.sleep(random.uniform(0.5, 3))
browser.find_element_by_css_selector('div.AnswerForm-editor').click()
time.sleep(random.uniform(0.5, 2))
js="""
var div=document.getElementsByClassName('public-DraftStyleDefault-block')
var text =document.createTextNode("君");
div[0].firstChild.appendChild(text)
"""
self.browser.execute_script(js)
browser.find_element_by_css_selector('Button.Button.AnswerForm-submit').click()
```

**Summary of problem:**

My problem is that I wrote the content to the answer box successfully, but I was identified as a machine.  After that, my actions on the page seemed to stop working.  How can I avoid being identified as a machine so that I can still use selenium to select my element?

Comment: Why _only human_? Why not _selenium_? What error do you see?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure where you are trying to select the submit button, but the following selector worked for me:

```
browser.find_element_by_css_selector('Button.Button.AnswerForm-submit').click()
```

With respect to being detected as a 'machine', it's not easy to avoid that. 
 There are several different ways they can detect you.

That said, here's one thing I found that can avoid some of the Selenium detection attempts. One thing they look for document variables called `$cdc_` and `$wdc_` that selenium uses, and for Chrome it would be `$cdc_`.  Here is what I suggest you try:

1. Download a hex editor if you don't already have one.  I used one from [here](https://mh-nexus.de/en/downloads.php?product=HxD20).
2. open your chromedriver.exe in the hex editor.
3. Use the Search functionality to find any instance of `$cdc_` or `$wdc_` and replace basically any other string ending in an underscore.  Myself, I found just one instance of `$cdc_`, and it looked like this:

   ```
   '$cdc_asdjflasutopfhvcZLmcfl_'
   ```

I simply replaced it with `'Random_'`

Hopefully this works and now you can traverse the site unimpeded.  If not, try some of the following; the only problem with this is that it **might** break your chromedriver file so that the tests no longer work.  But it could be worth a try, and if it does break you can easily download a fresh one.

4. Search the document for any usage of the words 'selenium', 'webdriver', or 'chromedriver' and delete them.  These is another way that a site can tell you are using selenium.

Let me know if any of this helps or you have any questions.  It's hard for me to come up with a concrete answer because I don't know how exactly the site is detecting selenium.

Comment: thanks,My problem is that I wrote the content to the answer box, but I was identified as a machine, which caused me to click the submit button and it was invalid.

Comment: Ah sounds like spam protection. Oh well I guess

Comment: I don't know for certain if it will work for you on this site, but I added in my answer some things that you could try to get past the bot detector.

Comment: selenium send_keys only support input , not support span?

Comment: What?  I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: Oh, I see, you want to send keys to a span element. I don’t think that works. You could try: 
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].innerText = 'test'", yourSpanElement)

Comment: now i use pyautogui  fill in the content,because use js recognized as a robot

Comment: Just curious if you tried changing your chromedriver file and it still detected you?  Or you just decided to use pyautogui instead.

Comment: Just use pyautogui temporarily